# Need to match the Coordinate system on vector and raster datasets

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a google satellite image that I am using as my basemap. The problem is that the shp files that I got from some source are projected in WGS 1984 UTM, Zone 42 North, Meter, but its GCS is 'unnamed'. I tried using 'go to xy' with the raster image and everything seems to be fine there. Although I tried projected the datasets using 'define projection' too but to no use.

When I simply drag the shapefiles over the raster image there is just a slight difference between the projection. I need the datasets to align accurately.

Comment: Depending on the country, it might be some version of Kalianpur datum instead of WGS84.